# Lightbend Reactive Architecture Certification

Tags: domain-driven-design, microservices, cqrs, reactive, event-sourcing

Does anyone know this certification? Opinions?

https://www.lightbend.com/certified-reactive-architect

Answer (score 6):

Yes I know this certification and have completed the same.
The syllabus of this certification is really awesome and will help you enhance your thinking and change the way you may think about the architectures traditionally.
It is related to Microservice Architecture. It will teach you to build the reactive system from scratch.
It teaches you how to think and interact with the customers/subject matter experts with the help of DDD(Domain Driven Design). It teaches you how to make Microservice Responsive, Resilient, Elastic and Message Driven. It adheres to reactive manifesto. It also teaches you microservice design patterns like Saga, CQRS and ES patterns. Architect systems using Hexagonal Architecture/ Onion Architecture where domain is the core of architecture.
It teaches you about CAP theorem too which is Consistency, Availability and Partiton Tolerance in depth.
Akka Toolkit, Lagom framework, Axon Framework, Eventuate Framework, Kafka, Cassandra and many more, follow these Principles and will really help us in understanding many more frameworks based on this Manifesto.
It basically will help you design the Systems with zero downtime.(Reactive Systems like, LinkedIn, Facebook, Twitter etc..)
It also helps you understand application partitioning, clustering, remoting, sharding, etc..
Overall I rate this certification as a 5 star and will help you think like an architect and may help achieve your goal of becoming the technical architect.